# Redirect cPanel url to something different

Tags: linux, cpanel

I have example.com which is the domain that hosts other domains.

On cPanel normally you can get to the actual cPanel by visiting `cpanel.hosteddomainA.com`, `hosteddomainA.com/cpanel` or `hosteddomainA.com:2082`

What I would like to accomplish is to have the hosteddomains cPanel auto redirect to something like `my.example.com:2082` . Doing this would allow me to adequately throw an SSL cert in `my.` and really offer a secure experience to my users.

I know it's possible because bluehost does the same. They redirect to my.bluehost.com.

Can anyone think of how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You could try putting something like this in the htaccess file of your main domain's document root or in the vhost config:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^my\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cpanel\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/cpanel
RewriteRule ^ http://my.masterdomain.com:2082/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: That would redirect `cpanel.domain.com` and `domain.com/cpanel` but is there also a way to redirect `domain.com:2082`? I like where you're headed though.. I will add that in as a start.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a CNAME DNS record with the subdomain my.example.com pointing to example.com. This way, the user will be able to access any of the resources available on example.com (such as example.com/cpanel) but will be a part of the my.example.com subdomain.

A CNAME DNS record, btw, creates an "alias" to another subdomain or domain. It is NOT a good idea to create a CNAME record for the root/apex domain, e.g. a CNAME record from example.com pointing to www.example.com.

Comment: Does the person who downvoted this care to explain why this is not a valid or technically-correct answer?